# Check memory used for each calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel that contains about 20 sheets. I have hundreds of calculations among those sheets. Is it possible for me to figure out a way to find how many memory is being used for each calculation?

Update: I found out the issue for the memory leak, which was caused by a destructor, but I thought the question above would still be a reasonable one for excel-vba.

Comment: There is no direct VBA link to the internals of the Excel calculation engine. You could monitor system RAM, specifically how much is used by the Excel process, though it wouldn't be easy (by using the Microsoft Scripting Runtime). This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What problem are you really needing to solve?

Comment: @JohnColeman I have a c++ program for calculation and I'm using excel to test it. By running calculation for the whole sheet twice I found that there is some memory leak. Since there are hundreds of calculations, I want to find out which calculation causes the memory leak by monitoring excel's memory.

Comment: Monitoring the memory usage of the Excel process probably wouldn't give you the resolution needed to break down usage per calculation. Also, if it is C++ code which is behind the memory leak, it might not even be in the Excel process itself (this might depend on just how you are invoking the C++ functions. I don't know what happens behind the scenes when you e.g. register a dll). It is an interesting question but you might need to provide more details to get a solution.

Comment: @JohnColeman For the first time I ran the calculation on whole sheets, the memory takes about 722,296k. Without closing the excel, I used the same macro to calculate again, the memory takes about 768,908k. So I guess there might be some memory leak that can be monitored by excel?

Comment: this is anecdotal evidence. It might be that excel just didn't get around to freeing some unused memory yet. Have you confirmed conclusively that there's a memory leak there?

Comment: Also, have you disabled any & all Excel, COM, and VBE add-ins?

Comment: I would actually be surprised if if Excel wasn't performing quite a bit of caching in this case. If I were writing spreadsheet software, I'd only update intermediate results if I had to.

Comment: A *memory leak* would be if the cached data remained in memory after the worksheet is closed. As long as it's opened, RAM consumption going up means nothing other than Excel allocating more memory for its purposes.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Is there any way that I can detect whether the cached data is changing? Like can I monitor it by using task manager or something?

Comment: You could apply for a position in the Excel product team at Microsoft, attach a debugger and find out. Other than that...